# C# Change DataGridViewCell value not working

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two forms (Form1, Form2). Form1 displays the values of objects. Form2 allows the user to revise certain properties of a value from Form1.

*Side Note:  (In Form1, I programmatically create Tab Pages and in each Tab Page is one DataGridView)*

I am trying to transfer the new string value from Form2 to a DataGridView (that I can only get by name) from Form1.

I created a public Tab Control in Form1 that I can access and search for the DataGridView.

My code does not produce any errors, but the cell in the DataGridView does not change like its supposed to.

What Am I doing wrong?

```
//Form1
//Create public access to the TabControl on Form1
public TabControl xTabControl
{
   get
   {
       return tabControl1;
   }
}



//Form2
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   string newText = txtDescription.Text.ToString(); //New Text 
   string tabName = txtTabName.Text.ToString();   //Name of the Tab to reference

   int txtChanged = Int32.Parse(txtChanged.Text.ToString());  //0 = No Change, 1 = Change
   int jobID = Int32.Parse(hidJobID.Text.ToString());  //Job ID 
   int rowIndex = Int32.Parse(hidRowIndex.Text.ToString());  //The row we must reference in our DataGridView

   //Call the public method from Form1 to define the Tab Control
   TabControl tabControl = Form1.xTabControl;

   //Define the Tab Page
   TabPage tbpage = new TabPage();
   tbpage = tabControl.TabPages[tabName];

   //If there is a Tab Page with that name then revise the cell
   if (tbpage != null)
   {
       //Define a DataGridView object
       DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

       //Find the DataGridView inside the TabPage (there is only 1 per Tab Page)
       foreach (Control ctrl in tbpage.Controls)
       {
           dgv = (ctrl is DataGridView) ? (DataGridView)ctrl : dgv;
       }

       dgv.ReadOnly = false;

        DataGridViewCell cellDescription = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6];
        DataGridViewCell cellCatName = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7];
        DataGridViewCell cellCat = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8];

        if (txtChanged > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cellDescription.Value.ToString());  //<-- This returns the correct string on the DataGridView
            dgv.CurrentCell = cellDescription;
            cellDescription.ReadOnly = false;
            cellDescription.Value = newText;  //<-- This should update the Cell, but it isnt!
        } 
        else 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 scared SO users are trying to close this thread yet the reason they listed makes absolutely no sense. Yes, I did say in my title that my code wasn't working - however - I clearly show my code, explained what I tried, what isn't working, and what my desired output is. If you would have (1) even read my post you would know, (2) even finished reading the choice you selected you would see that your selection bears no merit. These people should be held accountable for flagging posts without reading them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly why your current code does not work as you describe. The first problem that the compiler should be complaining about is the line below:

```
int txtChanged = Int32.Parse(txtChanged.Text.ToString());  //0 = No Change, 1 = Change
```

Obviously the variable `txtChanged` cannot be a `string` and an `int`. I assume that originally `txtChanged` is the name of a `TextBox` on `Form2` where the user types a 0 for no change and 1 for a change. I simply renamed the `int` `txtChanged` to `changeValue` and changed this variable in the if statement to `if (changeValue > 0).`

Lastly, I am not sure if you are able to reference the parent forms tab control as you are. I put the public property to get the forms tab control as you have posted and it was not returning the tab control correctly. Again I get compile time error indicating that `Form1` does not contain a definition for `xTabControl`.

To simplify things, instead of making the Tab control a public variable and accessing this public variable from `Form2`, simply pass the `TabControl` to `Form2` This will allow for two way access, to either read from the parents tab control or write to it.

After these changes your code and appears to work as expected. I assume the text in the `TextBox` named `txtDescription` gets set into the parents `DataGridView` at row `rowIndex` column 6.

In `Form2` we want to make a global `TabControl` variable that will point to `Form1`’s passed `TabControl`. Then in `Form2`’s constructor add a `TabControl` parameter to its signature to allow the parent to pass its `TabControl` to `Form2`. Like below:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form {

  public TabControl tabControl;

  public Form2(TabControl parentTC) {
    InitializeComponent();
    tabControl = parentTC;
  }

  private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string newText = txtDescription.Text.ToString(); //New Text 
    string tabName = txtTabName.Text.ToString();   //Name of the Tab to reference

    //int txtChanged = Int32.Parse(txtChanged.Text.ToString());  <-- changed this variable name

    int changeValue = Int32.Parse(txtChanged.Text.ToString());  //0 = No Change, 1 = Change
    int jobID = Int32.Parse(hidJobID.Text.ToString());  //Job ID 
    int rowIndex = Int32.Parse(hidRowIndex.Text.ToString());  //The row we must reference in our DataGridView

    //Call the public method from Form1 to define the Tab Control
    //TabControl tabControl = Form1.xTabControl;  <-- This parent tab control is already defined above

    //Define the Tab Page
    TabPage tbpage = new TabPage();
    tbpage = tabControl.TabPages[tabName];

    //If there is a Tab Page with that name then revise the cell
    if (tbpage != null) {
      //Define a DataGridView object
      DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

      //Find the DataGridView inside the TabPage (there is only 1 per Tab Page)
      foreach (Control ctrl in tbpage.Controls) {
        dgv = (ctrl is DataGridView) ? (DataGridView)ctrl : dgv;
      }

      dgv.ReadOnly = false;

      DataGridViewCell cellDescription = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6];
      DataGridViewCell cellCatName = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7];
      DataGridViewCell cellCat = dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8];

      if (changeValue > 0) {
        MessageBox.Show(cellDescription.Value.ToString());  //<-- This returns the correct string on the DataGridView
        dgv.CurrentCell = cellDescription;
        cellDescription.ReadOnly = false;
        cellDescription.Value = newText;  //<-- This should update the Cell, but it isnt!
      }
      else {

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps. I will test it soon. But towards your first comment I am converting a string to an int. The control is a label. The compiler does not complain about it - now it might be inefficient -but this is the only way I can get the compiler to not complain if the string value was null.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. The line:   `int txtChanged = Int32.Parse(txtChanged.Text.ToString());` should give the error `Use of unassigned local variable txtChange` which makes sense. In the line you are creating a NEW `int` variable called `txtChanged` by trying to parse this new unassigned variable `txtChanged.Text.ToString()`. ints do not even have a Text property.

Comment: I am not getting that error because control is a label - therefore it stores a string value. I cannot store an int into a label - it reads it as a string.   I first gather the string value and convert it to an int.

Comment: ah i see. that's what I get for not copy/pasting my code. I apologize